# remainder when common term exists in numerator and denominator and congruence relation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

remainder of $\dfrac{10}{3}$ $=1$

remainder of $\dfrac{2×10}{2×3}$ $=2×1$

remainder of $\dfrac{3×10}{3×3}$ $=3×1$

> Therefore, can we generalize this as
>
> remainder of $\dfrac{a×b}{a×c}$ $=a$ × remainder of $\dfrac{b}{c}$

I know only the basics of Congruence relation. If the above property is true, how can I write it using Congruence Relation? To my understanding, this can be written as the following . Please correct me if I am wrong.

> $\dfrac{3×10}{3×3} \equiv 3×\dfrac{10}{3} \pmod 3$

Comment: Not following.  $\frac {2\times 10}{2\times 3}=\frac {10}3$ which has a remainder of $1$ as you pointed out.

Comment: Maybe it's just a poor notation.  If you said "the remainder of $a\times b$ when divided by $a\times c$ is $a$ times the remainder of $b$ when divided by $c$ then I'd agree.  After all, if $b=qc+r$  then $ab=q(ac)+ar$.

Comment: The notation *is* poor.  $\frac {2\times 10}{2\times 3}$ clearly is not meant to mean the division but the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have stated can be written as

If $b \equiv N \mod c \iff a*b \equiv aN \mod a*c$.

Comment: could you please tell me, what is this $\iff$ symbol, I always wanted to know, but did not know the keyword to google this. is it same as the symbol $\Rightarrow$

Comment: $\iff$ meas "if and only if"  $\implies$ means "if ... than".  This means the two statements are equivalent.  If one then the other if not one then not the other.   I am a unicorn $\iff$ I am a horse with a horn in its head.  I am a unicorn $\implies$ I am a horse with a horn.   I am a horse with a horn, $\implies$ I am a unicorn.  I am a unicorn $\implies$ I am mythological.  But I am mythologicsl $\not \implies $ I am a unicorn.  (I could be a dragon, or a hydra, or....)